# Entity Framework One-2-One Relationships, Foreign Keys not being used in queries, Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

We have two applications using the same DB. One app is a .NET core app using ef core, the other is .net 4.6.1 MVC app using ef6. We built a rule engine in the .net core app and are now trying to bring that engine into our MVC app but are having difficulties with EF relationships.

We have two required one2one tables:

```
public class RuleSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ActionSet ActionSet { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ActionSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RuleSetId { get; set; }

    public virtual RuleSet RuleSet { get; set; }
}
```

In our fluent model builder, I've tried

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<RuleSet>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.ActionSet)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.RuleSet)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Which results in both items being pulled in by the primary key "Id", the dependent item doesn't use the RuleSetId as it's association. Thus the wrong action set is pulled in.

We noticed when changing the HasKey from Id to RuleSetId, we pull in the correct ActionSet, but now all the dependents on ActionSet are incorrect.

```
        // brings in the right ActionSet, but the wrong dependents for ActionSet
        modelBuilder.Entity<BossActionSet>()
            .HasKey(x => x.RuleSetId);
```

We'd prefer not to change code in both apps, can anyone think of a way that we could accomplish our goal without changing the model?

Comment: EF6 doesn't support alternate keys, so 1-1 relationships must use the entity key as the foreign key.  So either make this a 1-many relationship, change the FK, or migrate to EF Core which does support this model.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.